# Reach in Hackmaster

Tags: combat, combat-maneuver, reach, hackmaster-5e

The rules for Hackmaster state that reach is calculated as five feet plus reach (p. 223). I am assuming this should be considered four feet for shorter races (as per their lesser reach as listed in racial cons). This means that someone human-sized using a dagger, will have an effective reach of 6 feet, whilst that same character using a halberd has a reach of 12 feet. My question is threefold:

1. Can someone with an effective reach of equal to or more than 10 feet attack someone adjacent (ɔ: standing on the same square or one of the eight squares surrounding him)?
2. When do you get to do a *Hold at Bay* (p. 228) attack? Any time someone enters your reach? If so, wouldn't this mean that a player who has long reach (ten feet or more, ɔ: two squares or further away) potentially could get numerous attacks on enemies attempting to approach within a short time span?
3. At which point are combatants with long reach (one or both of them) considered to be locked in combat?